# How to find sum of multiple inputs (inputs can increase by add button) from different containers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sum

```js
function appendDiv() {
  var e = "<div>\
  <button onclick='appendBox(this)'>ADD NUMBER BOX</button>\
  <input type='number' class='sumOfTotal' readonly>\
  </div>"
  $("body").append(e);
}

function appendBox(This) {
  var e = "<div><input type='number' class='number'></input>\
  <button onclick='removeNum(this)'>DELETE NUM</button></div>"
  $(This.closest('div')).append(e);
}

function removeNum(This) {
  $(This.closest('div')).remove();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lab2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button onclick="appendDiv()">ADD DIV</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

> I want to update value of sumOfTotal every time I change input values.
> BUT each of someOfTotal boxes values have to be their div's numbers'
> sum.
>
> Summary, each div has their own output (sumOfTotal) and inputs (number
> class). And each div's own output has to be its own numbers' sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will recommend using event listeners instead of the inline javascript. Try this

```js
function calculateSum($box){
    let numbers, sum;

    numbers = $box.find('.number'); // get all .number inputs
    numbers = numbers.filter((i, el) => !!el.value); // filter out empty fields
    numbers = numbers.map((i, el) => el.value).get(); // get entered values
    sum     = numbers.reduce((sum, val) => sum + parseFloat(val), 0); // sum numbers

    $box.find('.sumOfTotal').val(sum); // display sum
}

$('.append-div-btn').on('click', function(){
    $("body").append(`
        <div class="box">
            <button type="button" class="append-box-btn">ADD NUMBER BOX</button>
            <input type="number" class="sumOfTotal" readonly>
        </div>
    `);
});

$('body').on('click', '.append-box-btn', function(){
    $(this).parent().append(
        `<div>
            <input type="number" class="number"></input>
            <button type="button" class="remove-num-btn">DELETE NUM</button>
        </div>`
    )
}).on('click', '.remove-num-btn', function(){
    let $box = $(this).closest('.box');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    calculateSum($box);
}).on('input', '.number', function(){
    let $box = $(this).closest('.box');
    calculateSum($box);
});
```

```css
.box {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="append-div-btn">ADD DIV</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result of the sum in a cookie, with that you'll be able to get the result and to increment it as you wish!

Here are the function to get and set a cookie in JS:

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}


function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```